# Mysql join on three tables to get list of unique data

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show all those users from `Users` table, whose `id` is present in table `favorite_group_users` as `user_id` for a user whose `favorite_groups.id = favorite_group_users.id`.

I used below query but it is returning null.

```
select users.id as user_id, users.first_name as name, 
        favorite_groups.id as group_id, 
        favorite_groups_users.user_id as carrier_id
from users
inner join favorite_groups
    on users.id = favorite_groups.user_id
inner join favorite_groups_users
    on favorite_groups.id = favorite_groups_users.favorite_group_id
where users.id = 38;
```

Comment: There is some typo in your query change `where usres.id = 38;` into `where users.id = 38;` try with this correct one and let me know

Comment: IF YOU want to show `all those users from 'Users' table` THEN why the condition for one user only?(`where users.id=38`)

Comment: You say that the user id is in `favorite_groups_users.user_id`, but your query uses `favorite_groups.user_id`. Which is correct?

Comment: creator's id is in `favorite_group` table as  `user_id` column and the users of creator's group is in `favorite_groups_user` table as `user_id` column.
All users data is in `users` table. @Barmar

All i want to show is Unique users from all groups which are created by Creator and added users in that group.

Comment: Show some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: I suspect it should be `WHERE favorite_groups_users.user_id = 38`. But the question is really unclear.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/669761/8/0 check this link i am getting required output, in your case your are getting NULL as there may be no joint records for your query

Answer (score 0):

You may try nested select

```
select 
  favorite_groups.group_id, users_group.user_id
from 
  favorite_groups_users , 
  (select 
     favorite_groups_users.favorite_group_id, 
     users.user_id 
   from 
     users, favorite_groups_users 
   where 
     users.id = 38 and 
     users.id = favorite_groups.user_id
  ) users_group 
where 
   users_group.favorite_group_id=favorite_groups.group_id
```